# Is there a way to listen for reaction events on a specific Discord message id

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Let's say Person **A** has sent a message, with message ID "`A1`". How can I make my Bot listen to `messageReactionAdd` and `messageReactionRemove` events on that message, "`A1`"?

Comment: Can you update your question with any attempts you have made? you can read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to create a post we can actually help debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Collector. [`message.createReactionCollector({ ... })`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector)

You can read more about Collectors here: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html

### Edit (comments)

If the message id is not changing, you can just return from your listener if the id of the reacttion's message isn't what you want.

Example:

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction) => {
  if (reaction.message.id !== 'A1') return
  // Your code ...
})
client.on('messageReactionRemove', (reaction) => {
  if (reaction.message.id !== 'A1') return
  // Your code ...
})
```

Client emits a [`MessageReaction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageReaction).
you can get it's message using [`MessageReaction.message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageReaction?scrollTo=message)
and you can get it's id using [`Message.id`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=id),
which you compare to 'A1'.

If it's not equal to 'A1' you can return from the listener early using `return` keyword (so if the condition is true, you don't execute any more code in that function)

Comment: This bot's sole purpose would be this, but I need it to be on 24/7 doing this exact thing. Would that be possible with a collector?

Comment: If it is a single message all the time, you can just add a `messageReactionAdd` and `messageReactionRemove` listeners and check whether the id of the message is "A1".

Comment: It it isn't a single message all the time, which I guess is the problem here, you will need to have some sort of global ID / list of IDs, where you push IDs, and in your listener you can check whether the list of IDs contains `reaction.message.id`.

Comment: It's one message, message "A1" that needs to be checked 24/7, it never changes what message needs to be checked. Message "A1" isn't sent by the bot itself though, how would I add a listener to it (any discord.js doc pages for this?)

Comment: @Epicurious I've edited my answer with a solution to your problem. I don't think there is any way to add a listener directly to a message.